# get For relational operators or bitwise right shift as commandline argument

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to get command line arguments to main , my arguments are like a.dat > b.dat or a.dat b.dat >> c.dat but i can not get `>` or `>>`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(">", argv[i]))
        {
           printf("here is comes\n");
        }
        else    
        {
            printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows, you can enclose the argument in quotes, such as

```
conf a.dat ">" b.dat
```

and the system removes the quotes.

Comment: i need to run program conf `file1.dat file2.dat > file3.dat` from windows

Answer (score 4):

`>` and `>>` have special meaning in shells. If you want to pass them as arguments, you need to escape them. Like: `a.dat \> b.dat`, `a.dat b.dat \>\> c.dat`.

In most (all?) shells, `>` means *redirect* (truncate and write) output of command to a file and `>>` means *append* (existing content is preseved).
For example:

```
$ ls > out #overwrite or create a file called 'out' with the output of 'ls' command.

$ ls >> out2 #append or create a file called 'out2' with the output of 'ls' command.
```

Comment: They direct output into a file. I think it's worth mentioning what their purpose is.

Comment: `a.dat > b.dat ` take all the content o a.dat and write it to b.dat
`a.dat >> b.dat ` take all the content o a.dat and append it to b.dat

Comment: @hkn Correct. But only if `a.dat` is an executable. Similarly `>>` appends. I have updated the answer with some info on it.

Comment: The OP's comment under my answer says Windows, but some syntax like yours gives the message "The syntax of the command is incorrect", and other syntax (such as your first example), still redirects the output to file.

Comment: @WeatherVane For which command it fails with that message? That's only an example and I didn't know OP's using windows. Besides, the answer (i.e. escaping them) should work on Windows too.

Comment: `test a.dat \> b.dat` redirects output to `b.dat`.

Comment: @usr so there is no way for c programe (for example its name is conf) to run in cmd with command `conf a.dat > b.dat` btw my aim is overwrite content of b.dat and put content of a.dat into b.dat with c program :S

Comment: @hkn In your question you say, you want to pass `>` and `>>` as arguments to a C program. But now you say you want to redirect `a.dat` to `b.dat`. Can you clarify it? If you want to do `conf a.dat > b.dat` then where's that C program comes into play? And yes `conf a.dat > b.dat` redirects output of `conf a.dat` into `b.dat`.

Comment: @WeatherVane so i dont need to code any think for test `a.dat \> b.dat` , shell will fullfill its job?

Comment: @usr my aim is if i used program like `test a.dat b.dat c.dat` it will stdout user content of a,b,c
if `test a.dat > b.dat` redirects output to b.dat
if `test a.dat >> b.dat` append output to b.dat

Comment: @hkn in Windows console `conf a.dat \> b.dat` directs the output to `b.dat`. My answer says that for `conf a.dat ">" b.dat` the shell will pass those arguments to the program, after removing the quotes. Your snippet of code is looking for that `>`

Comment: I get it , i will expect commands  that includes > char like ">" , if i did not ask here i will probably deal with it till morning thanks for your help .